# Execute two different queries based on date from an sql file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to execute two different queries based on date from an sql file.

Suppose I have two merge queries , Merge query 1, Merge query 2.

Most importantly this has to be within an sql file and run from a script using sqlplus.

Condition is like this,

If current date is "April 1st"
Execute Merge query 1
For all other dates
Execute Merge query 2

I want to avoid stored procedure. This is in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlplus doesn't provide flow control (like IF statement) so the cleanest option is to use pl/sql block in the SQL script. Not a stored procedure just embed the whole logic into anonymous pl/sql block

> DECLARE
>
> ...
>
> BEGIN
>
> END;
>
> /

You go with selecting current date into a variable.

> SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') INTO some_var FROM DUAL

And execute queries inside of regular IF statement.